# Time taken by count query - Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to know the time taken by count query in elastic search, just like the search query query which contain **`took`** - time taken.

My Query looks like - 
`curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/index1/type1/_count"`

And result for that query -

```
{
   "count": 136,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 15,
      "successful": 15,
      "failed": 0
   }
}
```

Is there is any way so that I can get the time taken for count query just like search api?

Document for count API - [Count API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html)

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing this answer still its not supported by Elastic, raised a [feature request](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/66905) and mostly I will work on to add a support of it.

Answer (score 0):

A trick that can help with that is to use `_search`

- with `size` zero (so no restult will be returned);
- `track_total_hits` set to true (so it will count all hits, not only the ones in the result window); and
- `filter_path` equal to `took,htis.total.value`.

For example, I executed the query above in a cluster of mine...

```json
GET viagens-*/_search?filter_path=took,hits.total.value
{
  "size": 0,
  "track_total_hits": true,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

...and got this result:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 2589552
    }
  }
}
```

It does not profile the Count API itself, unfortunately, but has a similar result. Can be very useful as an alternative in some situations!